# How to get Html helper code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

After many attemps to get Html.ActionLink<> and Html.Image() methods from different assemblies without any success could you help find the source of these methods so that I can use them in my Web app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC source code is [available at codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home).

The Html Helper methods are located in the `HtmlHelper` class, in the namespace `System.Web.Mvc`.

Or, you can open the System.Web.Mvc DLL using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), and view the source for the HtmlHelper methods there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe post some code? Are you sure you're using MVC? Are you trying in your View? Are you doing something like the following?:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("myTextBox")%>
```

Comment: Yes I am using it in an MVC View. Html.Image(AppHelper.ImageUrl()"cart.gif")